# DataTables: loop through all rows and get value from specific cell on each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

By using this code I can loop thru all DataTable rows and show the row values:

```
var table = $('#Example').DataTable();

table.rows().every(function(){

    console.log(this.data());
});
```

But how can I get the value only from cell 3 on each row?

Comment: does cell 3 have a class?

Comment: cell 3 was an example, it can be whatever cell I want

Comment: @AndrewDaly and no it does not have a class

Comment: var dataRow = table.rows( ':nth-child(3)' ).data();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trial and error this is what ended up working for me:

```
var table = $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();

table.rows().every(function(){

    var Row=this.data();//store every row data in a variable

    console.log(Row[3]);//show Row + Cell index

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [columns().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().data())

```
let table = $('#example').DataTable();
let values = table.columns(2) // DataTables is zero-based
                    .data()  
                    .eq(0);  // Convert to 2D array
console.log(values);
```